# CardLayout JPanel displaying, but not responding to mouse input

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

**Problem 1:** The first JPanel will display, but does not appear to reach the actionPerformed() method within the ControlPanel Class. I envisioned using CardLayout to transition between the firstPanel and SecondPanel (in my actual project these would contain two very different game environments with game logic contained within each panel respectively).

I would like to be able to get each JPanel (firstPanel and SecondPanel) to respond to a mouse click and change to the other panel. Please let me know if there is any additional information you need. All the code below should be able to be pasted directly eclipse luna and compile. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class CardLayoutMCVE 
{
    Panel1 firstPanel = new Panel1();
    Panel2 secondPanel = new Panel2();
    ControlPanel controlPanel = new ControlPanel();
    CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
    String State, panel1 = "1", panel2 = "2";

    public CardLayoutMCVE()
    {

        firstPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        secondPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout MCVE");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(controlPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        controlPanel.setLayout(card);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new CardLayoutMCVE();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ControlPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        public ControlPanel()
        {
            this.setLayout(card);
            /*Which ever is added first is drawn first, regardless of the
             * actionPerformed method.*/
            this.add("Panel1", firstPanel);
            this.add("Panel2", secondPanel);
            Timer timer = new Timer(14, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(State == panel1)
            {
                card.show(controlPanel, "Panel1");
            }

            if(State == panel2)
            {
                card.show(controlPanel, "Panel2");
            }
        }

    }

    private class Panel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener
    {
        /*Because there is no image the rectangle is set to cover the entire
         * screen, so window should change to Cyan on mouse click*/
        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000 , 1000);

        public Panel1()
        {
            this.addMouseListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            if(rec1.contains(p));
            {
                State = panel2;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }}

    private class Panel2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener
    {
        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000 , 1000);

        public Panel2()
        {
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            Timer timer = new Timer(14, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            if(rec1.contains(p));
            {
                State = panel1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }}
}
```

Thanks Andrew Thompson for your helpful edits!

Comment: *"**MVCE** Java CardLayout JPanel not displaying?*
An MCVE needs to be one source file so it can be a single copy/paste before compiling and seeing the problem.
That single source file might contain more than once class, though only one can be `public`.
An MCVE (of a run-time problem) also needs a `main(String[])` to run it!

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I definitely did not meet those requirements.

Comment: An [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30353992/edit) (to add an actual, tested, MCVE) would be **way better** than an apology.  ;)

Comment: Design questions should go to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) in general.

Comment: `setBounds(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);` requires the screen to be at least 2000x2000. Use `pack()` instead.